# Steam Community Market - Wait Time Keeps Changing

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards, steam-community-market

I have steam cards that I want to sell, but I have to wait for the restriction to be lifted. **BUT** the problem with this is that the day the restriction gets lifted changes and becomes an even longer wait. The first original date was for the **30/11/2015**, it changed again (still was unable to use the market). It then changed to **20/1/2016**.

[image: Change of Date again]

(I went to New Zealand for the holidays from Australia. If this would have any effect on this, then please tell me).

On a side note, I Used to not have steam wallet funds, because the games that I have bought are from the store (JB-HI-FI, EB Games etc.) and are activated by code (Steam gift cards are expensive $50 = $72 AUD).

Comment: I think there was a change recently to the wait period

Comment: To my waiting period, or for everyone altogether??

Comment: @Matt07211 - Everyone alltogether most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while I had finally got some steam support, and they pointed out that

> In order to use the Community Market you are required to have a purchase of wallet credit or made a Steam purchase that is between 30 days and a year old and you have had Steam Guard enabled on your account for at least 15 days with no Steam Support assisted password changes. Please note, Wallet code redemption does not grant access to the Community Market.

And since then I have added wallet credit and purchased some games online, so now I just have to wait and see if this restriction gets lifted as now I meet the requirements.

P.s. The reason I didn't have wallet credit was because for me it was easier to buy the games from jb-hifi as all the files were on the disc saving me internet as It is limited for me.